The quotient polynomial algebra $A=\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/\langle x^n,y^2\rangle$ with $\deg(x)=2$ and $\deg(y)=m$ is free as graded-commutative algebra?
According with Hatcher's AT book (page 227):

The quotient polynomial algebra $A$ in my case would be free as graded commutative algebra if there exists a polynomial algebra $\mathbb{Z}_2[z,w]$ isomorphic as an algebra to $A$, but since $y^2=0$ in $A$, I think that this is not possible, and hence $A$ can be not free (independently of the values of $n$ and $m$).
The word "in general" in the book actually describes all the free graded commutative algebras? Maybe I need some clarifications about the relation of the affirmation in the book (in the context of free commutative algebras) with the specific definition of a general free $R$-algebra $A$ as an algebra with a set $X\subset A$ such that the set of all monomial products of elements of $X$ is a basis of $A$ as $R$-module.
Finally, I wanted to know if there is any theorem about sufficient conditions for a quotient of a free graded commutative $R$-algebra (polynomial) by an ideal, remains free as a free graded-commutative $R$-algebra.
Thanks in advance!

Please read more carefully. It says free graded commutative algebra.

I already fix the question, thanks!

Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information not otherwise present in your post.

(I'm assuming that by $\mathbb{Z}_2$, you mean the integers mod 2 and not the 2-adics, but it would be better to use less ambiguous notation.)
With mod 2 coefficients, free graded commutative algebras are precisely polynomial algebras. The algebra in your title is finite dimensional as a vector space (and has dimension greater than 1) and so cannot be isomorphic to a polynomial algebra: it is not free. In addition $y$ is nilpotent, and polynomial algebras do not have nilpotent elements, so again, this is not free.
With coefficients in a field $k$ of characteristic other than 2, free graded commutative algebras are those of the form
$$
k[x_1, x_2, \dots] \otimes \Lambda(y_1, y_2, \dots)
$$
where each $x_i$ is in even degree, each $y_i$ in odd degree. Such an algebra has a basis consisting of all monomials in the generators where no $y_i$ appears more than once. This is because in a graded commutative algebra over a field of characteristic other than 2, the square of any odd-dimensional class must be zero, so no such class can appear more than once in any monomial.
Your question about ideals probably has a similar answer to the corresponding question in the ungraded case: what conditions must there be on an ideal of $k[x_1, x_2, ...]$ in order for the quotient to be a polynomial algebra?
